# Corruption of a variable in a session bean using JSF/Spring

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I have a system that I've developed that has a variable in a session-scoped bean that is getting corrupted, I believe from crosstalk.

I am using JSF/Spring/Glassfish/Primefaces. Spring Framework 4.0.3, Java EE 7.0.

When I run through testing, everything logically works fine. But in the field with about a dozen concurrent users, I am seeing a gremlin popup where in one case an int variable that is actually constrained from the web page to be between 0-100, suddenly had over 15k.

I am actually fairly new to Java EE, so I'm concerned that I've created a poor design or something like that. In my software, a user logs in using Spring/JSF security and creates a Session bean (bean scoped in `faces-config.xml` for session).

The User landing page causes the creation of a request bean in the page flow to allow the user to select some basic parameters. These are "stored" in the session bean and the user chooses an option that opens a new page and causes another request bean to be created to support that activity. The user does some actions and creates more data that is stored to the original session bean. The user does some more actions and creates a new page and request bean. etc.

Essentially, for each new page, I create a request bean that allows the user to do some activities and that flows back to the session bean. Periodically at certain states in the user's activity it creates transaction that go to the database. I'm using `@Named` in each bean.

I use:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        OperatorSessionBean operatorSessionBean = (OperatorSessionBean) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{operatorSessionBean}", OperatorSessionBean.class);
```

to access the session bean from each request bean.

Right now, I have a Primefaces Spinner that is constrained to be 0-100 (along with other data input). Once all of the data has been collected, the user Submits and in servicing that event, the data is "set" in the session bean. I always use setters and getters for accessing the session data and have the data elements as private.

My main question is am I missing something major i.e. crappy design?

Secondarily, any suggestion on how to find the gremlin. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Java EE does not include Spring, so if you are using Spring, you are not using 'Java EE'. And if you are even using faces-config.xml, you are not even using Spring Managed Beans, but JSF managed beans. Using @Named suggests CDI (or Spring, kind of) And so yes, you then have a kind of 'crappy' design' that is not fully visible. I'd suggest dropping all at all beans configured in faces-config, and if you really need to use Spring, check on how to use Spring managed beans in JSF, but make sure you only use one stack for managing beans. Mixing things leads to unexpected/weird behaviour

Comment: Thx for the feedback. My understanding was that JEE was the "engine"  that JSF was a Framework that utilized JEE and that Spring was a Framework on top of JSF that provided some additional capabilities. We chose Spring primarily for the ability to securely manage users access. From tutorials, we tried many different methods for bean control. The @Named seemed to be the only convention that worked correctly. WRT faces-config.xml, that seemed to be the only way to get the beans to behave as expected for Request versus Session scoping.

Comment: If we are "out-to-lunch" on this concept, I'd love to be told that, Additionally with someone to explain how this is "supposed" to go! Just saying we are wrong is not as helpful. I'm inferring from your post that if we want to have Spring Managed Beans, we need to define the scope of the beans somewhere other than faces-config?

Comment: _"I'm inferring from your post that if we want to have Spring Managed Beans, we need to define the scope of the beans somewhere other than faces-config?"_ Correct.

Comment: And Stackoverflow is not the site to provide full custom tutorials/training. Sorry if that is what you expected. JSF is part of JEE and uses to an extend other parts of JEE (e.g. when you use CDI, EL etc). Spring is certainly not a framework on top of jsf, heck it even more or less competes with jsf in its spring-mvc framework and spring by itself is a competitor of JEE. If you want to use JEE and have a good security framework that better integrates with JEE (and thus JSF) choose PicketLink or Shiro.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I did a lot of reading and tried several techniques from various tutorials. the blog post http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/integrate-jsf-2-spring-3-nicely/ was helpful as were several others. I found many tutorials and posts that appeared to suggest that these technologies would work together seamlessly, but obviously they did not. From what I read and experimented, these various technologies can live together but with a lot of (IMO) complexity. Therefore, I moved to using standard CDI for bean scoping. I'm using @Named and @RequestScoped or @SessionScoped. The key is to keep the Spring versus JSF/CDI fairly separate. I still use Spring purely for the login security. I found that the injection of Spring beans into JSF or CDI beans could work, but there was a fair amount of hassle with Serialization and such. For me, the added complexity was not worth the effort. The approach we ended up with, using Spring for login security and CDI for normal beans appears to be stable. The only issue I have is that within a browser on a specific host, if the user opens more than one window, the identity is shared i.e. you cannot reasonably have multiple user logins from a single computer using the same family of browser. For testing, that is a bit of hassle, but for our real application it is ok. So my basic question was resolved. Thx for comments.